# Apex Trigger Based On Related Links Changes

Tags: apex, trigger, related-list

I want to sum the number of Opportunities Related Links using a field trigger (I know I can do a roll up summary, but i cant use it as it is unclickable for the object I am using); I was wondering how I could trigger an Apex Trigger based off changes to the related links of an object?

Comment: welcome to SFSE; your question is a bit unclear. Please see [ask] to clarify using [edit]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Triggers fire only upon changes to the object type to which they are assigned; that is

```
trigger MyTrigger on Account (before update) {
```

will only ever run on changes to the Account record. While those changes may be fired indirectly through sequences of events that start with a child record update, via automation, other Apex code, or roll-up summary fields, the trigger will only ever execute if an Account is affected by DML.

You cannot use a Roll-Up Summary Field in a situation where records are related by a Lookup Relationship, or if the criteria involve a formula field or anything else that falls outside the narrow scope of allowed criteria for a Roll-Up Summary Field.

Your other options are basically roll your own RUSF using Apex triggers, which will involve a *child object* trigger and possibly also a parent trigger (for parents that support merges), or use a tool like the free, open source [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) package, which I recommend all the time. DLRS allows you to build roll ups across lookup relationships and use complex criteria.